# Is it possible to pass variables from Jinja2 to function in Javascript without writing <script> in HTML?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I'm using Flask for the course project. I have some javascript, and HTML files in `static` and `templates` folder, the hierarchy looks like this:

```
/flask_project
-->/run.py
-->/templates
  -->/index.html
-->/js
  -->/chart.js
```

There is a function in `chart.js` that can draw plots, and I need to pass some data from my python code to this function.

```
@app.route('/index')
    def index():
        data=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
        return render_template('index.html',data=data)
```

and in my `index.html`, I have

```
<script src="{{url_for('static',filename='chart.js')}}"></script>
```

and in my `chart.js` I have a function

```
draw(data){...}
```

I want to pass my data to this function, but if I add `var data={{data}}` in `.js` file, it will give me an error.

I know it would work if I copy codes from `.js` to `<scripts></scripts>` in `index.html` file, but it's very long and will make the HTML file looks ugly.

So is there any way that I can pass variables directly from jinja2 to javascript? Like calling the function `draw({{data}})` in `index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways:

a) render the data via Jinja into data attributes and read it via Javascript, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

b) call your backend via Javascript and retrieve the data; in early times this was done with jQuery.ajax(); nowadays you would probably use `fetch` API from pure Javascript

Answer (score 0):

According to [Flask's documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#standard-filters), try adding `|tojson` to your Jinja code.

`chart.js`

```
var data = {{data|tojson}}
draw(data){...}
```

I haven't tried running your code, but try messing with sending `data` from your endpoint as JSON if it doesn't work using this method right away.